# How can I create a Plane in Unity, that always shows up when using the AR-Camera in an App

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I have an AR app, where I want to have a plane with text on it, that is always shown when using the AR-Camera.
The Programm only uses the AR-Camera. The Plane doesn´t show up at all so far, even though it does in the preview.
The Plane doesn´t show up anywhere in the AR environment.

I don´t really know what to add since I think the question is simple. If you need further details just let me know.

Little Update: After the start of the app and after the Unity Logo shows up, the screen is black for a few seconds and during that time I can see my Panel on the black background. As soon as the AR-Camera is activated, the Panel is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in 3 simple steps:

1. You need to add a Plane object to your Unity's scene
2. You have to align the Plane in the view of your main Camera's object, to your liking
3. You have to set the Plane as a child of your Camera's object by simply dragging your Plane entry to Camera entry in the Scene Tree Editor Pane (located in most cases on the left side of your Editor's window)

Comment: I don´t know how to add pictures so I´ll write it here. Thanks for your answer. I already know some basics of Unity and already did these steps. The Plane doesn´t show up in AR mode though. Even though, as I mentioned, in Unity the Plane is visible in Camera preview.